# Geocoder gem 'rake geocode:all CLASS=Model' not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, geocoding, google-geocoding-api, rails-geocoder

I have a Ruby on Rails app with geocoder gem installed. I am trying to bulk geocode all rows (approx. 2500) in my database with rake geocode:all. When I run the command nothing happened. None of the rows were geocoded. Am I missing something here?

Model.rb

```
geocoded_by :fulladdress  
after_validation :geocode

def fulladdress                                         
  [address, city, state, zip].compact.join(",")  
end
```

Comment: you are using active record or mongoid?

Comment: latitude, longitude field is there in db right?

Comment: only if you are using active record

Comment: yes i am using active record..and yes latitude and longitude columns are present in my table.

Comment: Could you show what you have in your other files as well?

Answer (score 2):

Just try to run outside of the Rake task manually (e.g. rails console or rails runner):

```
Model.find_each {|m| m.save! }
```

If you do it in development have a quick look over the outputted SQL Statements, if there lines with "UPDATE models SET lat=?, lon=? ..."

Comment: 'rake geocode:all CLASS=Model' command is not outputting anything..and what can I check with 'Model.find_each {|m| m.save! }' ..i didn't get you exactly.

Comment: This will run the validation + saving for all your models. Your code looks fine, the save will run your geocoding, too. Any error should be raised by the "save!". If you are using Google as your Geocoding Backend, make also sure to include a sleep 1, otherwise you will be throttled.